# USB Drive Only Detected If Connected At Boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, hardware-detection

I'm running Elementary OS, a Linux distro based on Ubuntu.

My computer would only detect a USB device (including USB flash drives, portable hard drives, graphic tablets, etc.) if it is connected before I boot the computer.

Any device connected while the computer is running is not recognized in any way. That means it doesn't show up in hardinfo under USB Devices, it doesn't show up in lsusb, and when it's a USB flash drive, the light on the USB does not light up at all.

Everything works normally if I plug the device in before I start the computer.

I tried turning Plug and Play OS on and off in the BIOS settings, but nothing changed.

Does anyone know what I can do so that any new USB device is detected immediately when they are plugged in, while the computer is on?